# Where does python get the local timezone from?

Tags: python, datetime

```
>>> import time
>>> time.tzname
('GMT', 'BST')
```

Where does Python get this information (the local timezone) from? Is there a syscall that returns this? I see some sources mentioning a `/etc/timezone` file, and others mentioning a `TZ` environment variable.

I see that Python honors the `TZ` environment variable if set:

```
TZ="Asia/Calcutta" python -c "import time; print(time.tzname)"
('IST', 'IST')
```

My shell doesn't have this set by default though, so I'm curious how the local timezone is read when the `TZ` environment variable isn't present.

Comment: syscall? No, this is not a task of kernel. Python get a lot system data from standard C library (e.g. much of datetime) and other system libraries (you may find different availability between operating systems). So it depends on your system and on on which libraries your python interpreter is linked to.

Comment: Source code of `time` module of `python` is available at [cpython github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/timemodule.c). It is C, which I do not understand correctly enough to detect what you want. Maybe some C-ninja will be able to answer your question after look at said code.

Comment: you can also jump those hoops in Python (does not need to be C), see e.g. the [tzlocal source code](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal/tree/master/tzlocal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depends upon the platform you are using. If you are on windows, you assumption is correct, it makes [`GetTimeZoneInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-gettimezoneinformation) system call to create the `time.tzname` tuple. [Here is](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/timemodule.c#L1757) the relevant part of the `C` code.

```
#ifdef MS_WINDOWS
    TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION tzinfo = {0};
    GetTimeZoneInformation(&tzinfo);
    otz0 = PyUnicode_FromWideChar(tzinfo.StandardName, -1);
    if (otz0 == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    otz1 = PyUnicode_FromWideChar(tzinfo.DaylightName, -1);
    if (otz1 == NULL) {
        Py_DECREF(otz0);
        return -1;
    }
#else
    // Skipped for brevity
#endif // MS_WINDOWS
    PyObject *tzname_obj = Py_BuildValue("(NN)", otz0, otz1);
    if (tzname_obj == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "tzname", tzname_obj);
```

But where as in other platform it completely depends upon the [`tzname` variable](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/timemodule.c#L49) which is initialized by the [`tzset()` function in the `C` standard library](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tzset.3.html).

> The `tzset()` function initializes the `tzname` variable from the `TZ`
> environment variable.  This function is automatically called by the
> other time conversion functions that depend on the timezone. In a
> System-V-like environment, it will also set the variables timezone
> (seconds West of UTC) and daylight (to 0 if this timezone does not
> have any daylight saving time rules, or to nonzero if there is a time,
> past, present, or future when daylight saving time applies).
>
> If the `TZ` variable does not appear in the environment, the system
> timezone is used.  The system timezone is configured by copying, or
> linking, a file in the tzfile(5) format to `/etc/localtime`.  A timezone
> database of these files may be located in the system timezone
> directory (see the FILES section below).
>
> If the `TZ` variable does appear in the environment, but its value is
> empty, or its value cannot be interpreted using any of the formats
> specified below, then Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) is used.